# What is a meaning of suffix "nip" in "Catnip"?

Tags: meaning, etymology, nouns, suffixes

I tried to google it, but it seemed to be lack of sensible answer. So, I ask you questions:

What is a meaning of suffix "nip" in "Catnip"? and Where is it come from?

Comment: Also possibly Turnip and Parsnip?  I turned up this http://listsearches.rootsweb.com/th/read/WORDS/2000-09/0969016165

Comment: @Blandorthin: *catnip* is an herb, not a brand name.

Comment: @pcarr the nip in parsnip/turnip is from neep according to http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=parsnip and  http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=neep which is separate.

Comment: @k1eran ...and you didn't bother to answer the question with [the etymology of catnip from the same source](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=catnip) ?

Comment: @Mitch What do you mean? Peter Shor has already provided an (accepted) answer using that source i.e. http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=catnip Here I am only only commenting on parsnip/turnip point in the comment above. And in my own answer I tried deliberately to provide an alternative perspective rather than duplicating Peter's etymonline.com one.

Comment: @k1eran oh. sorry. The edit queue didn't show the actual answers just the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Catnip](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=catnip) comes from *cat* + *nip*, where *nip* comes from *nepte*. Here *nepte* is the Old English name of catnip or of a family of herbs including catnip, and originally comes from Latin *nepeta* (with the same meaning).

Reference: Etymonline

Answer (score 11):

As @peter-shor's answer says already :   ***nip*** [...] comes from Latin **nepeta** [...] family of herbs. Regarding the source of the **nepeta** genus, quoting  [Floral Centric [...]](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=JrQYAAAAYAAJ&lpg=PA67&ots=xHT-tukDmu&dq=Nepeta%20city%20etymology&pg=PA67#v=onepage&q=Nepeta%20city%20etymology&f=false) by William Darlington in 1826:

[image]

Same [**Nepeta** genus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nepeta) root (ie. the ancient [Etruscan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etruscan_cities) city) is quoted in David Gledhill's [The Names of Plants](http://www.agrifs.ir/sites/default/files/the_names_of_plants_gledhill.pdf):

> **Nepeta** the Latin name, from Nepi, Italy

Answer (score -6):

"Nip" comes from Germanic words that suggest holding or pinching. The root is Indo-European. It can be seen in OLD Norse and Dutch with almost the same meaning. The word currently being used in Punjabi 'nup' has the same meaning. If a cat is attracted to the smell that comes from catnip, the olfactory sense holds the cat in bondage.

Comment: From my reading the nip in catnip is completely unrelated to the standalone English word nip  that you describe here.